# Plot text and shapes at x,y distance from plot margins in R

Tags: r, plot

To visualize power with different values of N, effect sizes, and variances I am simulating and plotting the data below:

Libraries:

```
library(repr)
library(plotrix)
```

```
# N = sample size
N = 1000

# Sample 1
x_gi = rnorm(N, mean=38.3, sd=8)
# Plot
x_gi_hist=hist(x_gi ,
     breaks=25,
     main=expression(paste(italic(bar(x)[0]))),
     xlab="taurine per unit of something",
     col="firebrick")

# Sample 2
x_gf = rnorm(N, mean=20, sd=7)
# Plot
x_gf_hist=hist(x_gf ,
     breaks=25,
     main=expression(paste(italic(bar(x)[gf]))),
     xlab="taurine per unit of something",
     col="grey70")

# Both samples together
#####################
# H0: Grain-inclusive distribution
# Plot
plot(x_gi_hist,
     col= c("firebrick",rgb(0.8,0,0,1/2))[cut(x_gi_hist$breaks, c(-Inf, max(sort(x_gi)[(1: (length(x_gi)*0.05))]),Inf))],   
     xlim=c(0,75), ylim=c(0,N/5),
     main="", xlab="taurine per unit of something",
     cex.lab=1.5,
     border=c("firebrick",rgb(0.7,0,0,1/4)))
# H0 label
text(x=mean(x_gi), y=max(x_gi_hist$counts) + (N/15),
    label = expression(paste(italic(H[0]))),
    cex=2)
# Mean label 
text(x=mean(x_gi), y=max(x_gi_hist$counts) + (N/30),
    label = expression(paste(italic(bar(x)[0]))),
    cex=2)

# Critical value
ablineclip(v=max(sort(x_gi)[(1: (length(x_gi)*0.05))]+0.8),
           lwd=2, lty=2, col="red",
           y1=0, y2=max(x_gf_hist$counts)-5)
# Critical value
text(x=max(sort(x_gi)[(1: (length(x_gi)*0.05))]+0.8), y=max(x_gf_hist$counts)-4,
    label="critical value", adj=0,cex= 1.5)

# Effect size arrow
arrows(x0=mean(x_gf)+4, x1=mean(x_gi)-4,
       y0=max(x_gi_hist$counts) + (N/30), y1=max(x_gi_hist$counts) + (N/30),
       lty=1, code=3, lwd=3, col="black")
# Effect size label
text(x=mean(x_gf) + (1/4 * mean(x_gi)), y=max(x_gi_hist$counts) + (N/25),
    label = expression(paste(italic(d))),
    cex=2)

#####################
# HA: Grain-free distribution
# Plot GF
plot(x_gf_hist,
     col= c(rgb(0,0,0,0.2), rgb(0,0,0,0.5))[cut(x_gf_hist$breaks, c(-Inf, max(sort(x_gi)[(1: (length(x_gi)*0.05))]),Inf))],  
     xlim=c(0,75),ylim=c(0,N/5),
     add=T, border=rgb(0,0,0,0.2))
# HA label
text(x=mean(x_gf), y=max(x_gi_hist$counts) + (N/15),
    label = expression(paste(italic(H[A]))),
    cex=2)
# Mean label 
text(x=mean(x_gf), y=max(x_gi_hist$counts) + (N/30),
    label = expression(paste(italic(bar(x)[gf]))),
    cex=2, font=2)
```

This works when N > 100 but breaks down when N<10.

**Question**: is there a way to generate sensible plots across lower values of N, say when N=10

Here is an example:

[image: Here is an example:]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The truth/decision box doesn’t change? If so, no reason it couldn’t be a seperate object, arranged with the plot using a package like cowplot or patchwork?

Comment: Thanks Mark Neal. Yes this is true, however we still need to move the over text, symbols, etc, in response to different values of N.

Comment: Consider simplifying your question by removing the confusion matrix. Then show a second example plot where the current *essential* code doesn’t work for N=Ni. That will help identify which parameters are problematic.

Comment: Sure @MarkNeal, I'll post above...

Comment: I've run the code. A couple of points: For a reproducible example, include packages required (plotrix?). I would make N a parameter, then show the plots for N=1000, and N=100000 - only one set of code. I would also make it easier to cut and paste by having it as one code chunk - make "Sample 1:" a comment in the code chunk. I do not get the same plot as your first successful attempt, due to different code. Create the plots to your preferred picture dimensions with a ggsave() call with width=x and height=y, so at least we can be sure we are looking at the same output.

Comment: Initial thoughts - Have you considered scaling frequency to relative frequency? Or using ggplot, with which more people will be familiar? Having made the switch early in my career, I've never regretted it! And as I've worked out you didn't use ggplot, you can't use the ggsave() command to ensure we are looking at the same thing - some *save* to png is required, otherwise what we each see is subject to our own viewbox size and proportions.

Comment: Yes, I tried ```freq=F```. Similar problems result. Sure, I like both base R and ggplot. If this can be solved with ggplot, I will definitely convert. Just to be clear. I am using jupyer lab, not R or R studio IDEs. Thanks again for working through this with me!

Comment: Can you consolidate the code as per my suggestion, with N as a parameter? That cuts the post in half and may encourage someone else to jump in with an answer before I have time to attempt it. The confusion matrix would be best created as a seperate object, then combined with the histogram plot to the side or below using cowplot, patchwork or grid.arrange (that could be the subject of a seperate question later). One reason to prefer ggplot is that when done in a curtain way, it will choose sensible axes. Base plot axes are determined by the first plot, and everything you add will fit, or not.

Comment: Sure, Mark. I think this ^ works now.... I still need to figure out how to scale the size of the confusion matrix in jupyter but... otherwise. I think this works OK for now. Thank you!